# I cant seem to understand the logic behind the setNextPin() function in this code

Tags: python, inheritance, data-structures, python-class

I am reading this interactive book from runestone academy on Data structures and Algorithms (Source:  https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/pythonds/index.html) and i am having trouble understanding this particular setNextPin() function.

```
class Connector:

    def __init__(self, fgate, tgate):
        self.fromgate = fgate
        self.togate = tgate

        tgate.setNextPin(self)

    def getFrom(self):
        return self.fromgate

    def getTo(self):
        return self.togate
    

    def setNextPin(self,source):
        if self.pinA == None:
            self.pinA = source
        else:
            if self.pinB == None:
                self.pinB = source
            else:
                raise RuntimeError("Error: NO EMPTY PINS")
```

What's the source and self in this and how are we setting the value of the pin to the connector?

Comment: These kind of questions aren't really what SO is for as you could easily just Google for an answer eg [Understanding self in Python](https://medium.com/quick-code/understanding-self-in-python-a3704319e5f0)

Comment: ah okay, sorry i am new here. Should i just delete the question now?